# route not work in CodeIgniter for others routes than home

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to run CodeIgniter in localhost under Kubuntu O.S..
For the home URL (http://localhost) it works without problems. But when I try to access to another URL (http://localhost/cliente) he says "The requested URL /cliente was not found on this server.".

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['cliente'] = 'clientes';
$route['produto'] = 'produtos';
```

I have the Clientes.php and the Produtos.php files in the application/controllers folder.

In the config.php: $config['index_page'] = '';

The most unusuall thing is when I call the welcome controller it works. Only not works when I try to call the others controllers. Like http://localhost/cliente.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is a problem with your .htaccess file. this is my version of it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

hope this helps, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Working with `lamp` on linux is a little bit different than `xampp` on windows, you have to manually enable a few settings.

Your rewrite rules won't work because `mod_rewrite` is disabled by default and you have to enable it first.

**Step 1 — Enabling `mod_rewrite`**

In order for Apache to understand rewrite rules, we first need to activate `mod_rewrite`. It's already installed, but it's disabled on a default Apache installation. Use the `a2enmod` command to enable the module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already enabled. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

`mod_rewrite` is now fully enabled. In the next step we will set up an `.htaccess` file that we'll use to define rewrite rules for redirects.

**Step 2 — Setting Up `.htaccess`**

An `.htaccess` file allows us to modify our rewrite rules without accessing server configuration files. For this reason, `.htaccess` is critical to your web application's security. The period that precedes the filename ensures that the file is hidden.

By default, Apache prohibits using an `.htaccess` file to apply rewrite rules, so first you need to allow changes to the file. Open the default Apache configuration file using nano or your favorite text editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Inside that file, you will find a `<VirtualHost *:80>` block starting on the first line. Inside of that block, add the following new block so your configuration file looks like the following. Make sure that all blocks are properly indented.

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Save and close the file. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Now, create an `.htaccess` file in the web root.

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

Add this line at the top of the new file to activate the rewrite engine.

```
/var/www/html/.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
```

Save the file and exit.

You now have an operational `.htaccess` file which you can use to govern your web application's routing rules.

Comment: If I modify the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf as you say the Apache stops work.

Comment: I change the place in the file where I put de block and it works. I was put at the end and after I put at the top.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @LuisCarlosSilva .. you're welcome bro, there are a lot to take into consideration while working with lamp cause there are a lot of configurations that must be set manually, like error reporting for example (that's a problem that you'll face later), anyways .. please consider closing this question by approving the correct answer.